# Multiple Selects with Union disordered?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union

I have multiple selects joined by a Union as following

```sql
(
   select * from x
)
UNION
(
   select * from y
)
UNION
(
   select * from z
)
```

But I'm getting disordered results on the SSMS:

```
z results
x results
y results
```

Is it possible to force results to be x, y, z?

Comment: of course.Perform ORDER BY in the outer query

Comment: Unless an explicit `ORDER BY` is provided, SQL Server is free to return a result set in *whatever* arbitrary order it "feels like". Many things can effect the order a result set is returned in when an `ORDER BY` is omitted, including locks, parallelism, CPU/RAM resource availability, indexes (or a lack of), whether the data gets written to work table (in `tempdb`), the list goes on. Without an explicit `ORDER BY` any number of those factors could affect the order of the data, and the order could be different **every time** you run said query.

Comment: Side note, those parenthesis (`()`) aren't required in the query you have. Also, unless the data could explicitly contain duplicates you don't want (from the sample data you give, it suggests not) it is far more performant to use `UNION ALL`, as it doesn't have an implied `DISTINCT` operation on the final data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *must* provide an `ORDER BY` clause, otherwise no ordering is guaranteed. For example, the rows from different tables could even be interspersed.

**A good option for explicit ordering, is to add a column and order by it**

```sql
select *, 1 as ordering
  from x
UNION
select *, 2
  from y
UNION
select *, 3
  from z
order by ordering;
```

I suspect you actually don't need `UNION` here (which implies `DISTNCT`) and you really want `UNION ALL`.